# Kubernetes pod cpu usage percentage

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I try to calculate how many percent cpu of limits pod use. I try to use this expression:

```
sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cluster!="production",namespace="devops"}[2m])) by (pod_name) / kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{cluster!="production",namespace="devops"}
```

But it show 0 series. Left and right sided expressions return scalar values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below prometheus expression to give percentage CPU usage -

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name="abc"}[5m])) by (container_name) /sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{container_name="abc"}/container_spec_cpu_period{container_name="abc"}) by (container_name) *100
```

You can create your own custom dashboard in Grafana to get the data for last `x` number of days.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that not every pod container has **resource limits** of CPU cores. Therefore you get two vectors of different length and expression fails without an error message.

You can verify my guess the following way:

```
count(sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cluster!="production",namespace="devops"}[2m])) by (pod_name))
```

and:

```
count(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{cluster!="production",namespace="devops"})
```

These two values should be the same, if not - here is the reason your query doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, both query return equal count :)